# How to make an image black and white but leave certain parts in colour in photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, black-and-white, selective-color

I have taken some pictures over the weekend and think they will look good if the image was in black and white but the main subject was left in colour. I have Photoshop. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Selective color is  for if you want to keep only certain specific colors. This question sounds more like the OP wants specific items/areas to be left in full color regardless of hue and the rest of the photo converted to monochrome/gray scale. I've usually heard that referred to mores as "spot color."

Answer (score 1):

Just mask the area you want to keep in color, and desaturate the rest.

https://www.google.com/search?q=Masking+tutorial+photoshop

https://www.google.com/search?q=desaturating+in+photoshop